# how to get rows in the current pagination page in asp.net gridview c#

Tags: asp.net, gridview, pagination

I am using asp.net gridview with pagination/sorting which works perfectly.
I have a button outside the grid to say 'Approve current page' which is to get only the rows in the current page and send to db for processing.

```
BindGridView(){
//this will set the initial 
var firstPage = _clientList.Take(xgvClientApprovals.PageSize).ToList();
}
OnApproveClicked(){
    //this will get rows count in each paginated page but I am unable to get 
    //the data itself.
    var currentPageRows = xgvClientApprovals.Rows;
    //Here I would like to get only the current page rows.
}
```

Comment: You know the page index and you know the rows per page...

Comment: But I will get the unbound data, what if there is filter/sorting applied? The rows I get based on number of rows per page may be different to what is shown on the grid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `DataKeyNames` in the GridView to always get the correct data.

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" DataKeyNames="approvalID">
```

Then simply read the correct DataKey from the row

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < GridView1.Rows.Count; i++)
    {
        int approvalID = Convert.ToInt32(GridView1.DataKeys[i].Values[0]);
    }
}
```